# How to install apps on iPad 4 which require IOS version 11 or higher?

Tags: ios, ipad, applications

Just borrowed an old ipad 4 from a friend and found out that i can't download most of the apps on it because the IOS updates are no longer available for this device. For almost all of the apps, i get an error: `The application requires IOS 11.0 or higher during install`.

I can't find any iOS updates in the software update and latest version on this device is iOS 10.3.4.

Is there any way to download these apps on my ipad?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answer is **No**, you can't do it. However, there are few workarounds and one I did a bit long time was:

1. You need to have a newer iOS device (if you do not have one, you can borrow one from a friend).
2. Make sure that you’re signed in to iCloud with the same Apple ID on both devices (if you are borrowing a device from a friend, your friend needs to log out first, your friend may want to make copies of the information that he stored in iCloud).
3. On your new device, launch the App Store and find the app and download and install it.
4. Now get the old device that you want to install the app. On your old device, go to App Store and then Purchased. You will see the app there because you just purchased it. İf you do not see it yet, just wait.

   [image]
5. And then tap the iCloud icon to download the app.
6. And the download will start.

Note that these methods may not work for all apps. This only works if the developer of the app had not deleted it from Apple’s App servers. Furthermore, since you are downloading an older version of the app, it is highly likely that not all features of the app may be available.

Comment: I think it's not required to own the apps in question, at least it wasn't in the past (I did it on iPad 1st gen, iOS 5.1.1, the last time). Even if it's a new purchase for the apple id in question, if your device's iOS isn't supported by the newest app version *and* there exists an older app version that *is* supported, it suggests you to download that instead.

Comment: @Gero Doesn't prompt me to download any older version in most cases. Could it be that even no older version is supported (seems improbable thought)?

Comment: That is very much a probability. I am an iOS developer myself and since the update rate among iOS users is so high, we often only submit app bundles (for a new version) that supports the current and the last version. That means the last time I uploaded an iOS 10 build was over 2 years ago. As a dev I can decide to disallow older versions of my app and although I've never done this in the past I assume any app that has some sort of backend communication eventually does this (that way we can phase out deprecated APIs and so on). They simply won't work anymore once the backend changed too much.

Comment: addendum: Look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34513934/710041) for how that looks for us developers when managing an app. By "disallow" I meant "redownload" as described by Udhy. An app that's installed already can't be "removed" from your device by me (or any dev) with this (though obviously the time could come when it no longer works with a backend and crashes). As said I think "redownload" also includes new purchases, but I'm not 100% sure. I _think_ I've done this with the Youtube app myself in the past, but that's been quite a while.